# Braintree/PayPal Version 3 Upgrade issue

Tags: braintree

I just tried to upgrade to v3 version of BrainTree/Paypal and getting error on braintree.client.create call (braintree.create is undefined).

I am pointing to the following JS files - https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js
https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.33.0/js/client.min.js
https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.33.0/js/paypal-checkout.min.js

JS code -
                braintree.client.create({
                      authorization: token
                    }, function (err, clientInstance) {
                      // ...
                    });

Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Can you share the error message you are getting and the part of your code that is trying to create the Braintree client instance?

Comment: Thanks for the concern, this was resolved. The issue was because our code had V2 version also defined in the JS, once V2 JS was removed this worked.